# Replacing missing quarter and missing data per quarter

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series, zoo

## Background

I've a quarterly data set where certain quarters and corresponding values are missing. The characteristics of the data set are:

- Each group *should have* the same number of quarters but in practe quarters are missing
- For missing quarter values are unknown

  - This is to be resolved by sourcing imputing next available value; for instance, as available via [`na.locf`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-0/topics/na.locf) function

### Example data

```
# Packages
Vectorize(require)(package = c("tidyverse", "zoo", "magrittr"),
                   character.only = TRUE)

# Seed
set.seed(123)

# Dummy data
dta <- data.frame(group = rep(LETTERS[1:5], 10)) %>%
    group_by(group) %>%
    mutate(qrtr = seq(
        from = as.Date("01/01/2012", "%d/%m/%Y"),
        to = as.Date("31/5/2014", "%d/%m/%Y"),
        by = "quarter"
    )) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate(qrtr = as.yearqtr(qrtr)) %>%
    arrange(group, qrtr) %>%
    mutate(value = sample(1:10, 50, replace = TRUE))

# Remove random rows
dta[sample(1:dim(dta)[1], 10), c(2, 3)] <- NA
dta %<>% na.omit()
```

#### *Preview*

```
# A tibble: 40 x 3
   group          qrtr value
   <chr> <S3: yearqtr> <int>
 1     A       2012 Q1     3
 2     A       2012 Q2     8
 3     A       2012 Q4     9
 4     A       2013 Q1    10
 5     A       2013 Q3     6
 6     A       2013 Q4     9
 7     A       2014 Q1     6
 8     B       2012 Q1    10
 9     B       2012 Q2     5
10     B       2012 Q3     7
# ... with 30 more rows
```

## Problem

1. Create add rows **within** each group where quarter are missing. Total number of quarter is derived from sequence `min(qrtr)` to `max(qrtr)`, in the context of existing code:

   ```
   seq(from = as.Date("01/01/2012", "%d/%m/%Y"),
       to = as.Date("31/5/2014", "%d/%m/%Y"),
       by = "quarter")
   ```
2. First non-missing value should be carried forward for the missing value.

#### *Desired results:*

```
>> dta
# A tibble: 50 x 3
   group          qrtr value
   <chr> <S3: yearqtr> <int>
 1     A       2012 Q1     3
 2     A       2012 Q2     8
 3     A       2012 Q3     8
 4     A       2012 Q4     9
 5     A       2013 Q1    10
 6     A       2013 Q2    10
 7     A       2013 Q3     6
 8     A       2013 Q4     9
 9     A       2014 Q1     6
10     A       2015 Q1     6
# ... with 40 more rows
```

### Proposed approaches

One approach would rely on making use of the [`expand`](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/expand.html), in order to convert implicitly missing values to explicitly missing values. This so far creates missing quarters but there is no clear way of creating missing observations for `value` column for where given quarter is missing.

```
dta %>%
    # Append mixing quarters
    expand(group, qrtr) %>% 
    left_join(data.frame(qrtr = as.yearqtr(
        seq(
            from = as.Date("01/01/2012", "%d/%m/%Y"),
            to = as.Date("31/5/2014", "%d/%m/%Y"),
            by = "quarter"
        )
    )), by = "qrtr") %>%
    # TODO
    # mutate(value = na.locf(value)) %>% 
    arrange(group, qrtr) -> dta_fixed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems to be interested in `padr`

```
library(padr)
library(zoo)

#convert to POSIXct as pad() expect it to be like this
dta$qrtr <- as.POSIXct(dta$qrtr,format="%Y %q")
dta %>% 
  pad(group="group") %>% 
  arrange(group, qrtr) %>%
  mutate(qrtr = as.yearqtr(qrtr)) %>%
  na.locf()
```

output is:

```
# A tibble: 49 x 3
   group    qrtr value
   <chr>   <chr> <chr>
 1     A 2012 Q1     3
 2     A 2012 Q2     8
 3     A 2012 Q3     8
 4     A 2012 Q4     9
 5     A 2013 Q1    10
 6     A 2013 Q2    10
 7     A 2013 Q3     6
 8     A 2013 Q4     9
 9     A 2014 Q1     6
10     B 2012 Q1    10
# ... with 39 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks `pad` works well in that case; at the end I've used `as.Date` not `as.POSIXct` as `as.POSIXct` didn't work with the actual dates I had (not all groups had first and last date so I had to define span with use of `start_val` and `end_val` arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Use `read.zoo` to create a multivariate time series `z` with one column per group; merge that with a zero width series of quarters, run `na.locf` and then convert that back to long form.

We can omit:

- the line with the `merge` if there is no quarter missing from every group -- in the example data in the question this is the case. i.e. for the data in the question we could omit the `merge` (although if we left it in it would not cause a problem)
- the last line (the one with `fortify.zoo`) if we can work with the 10 x 5 multivariate time series `z` directly, which may actually be more convenient, e.g. `library(ggplot); autoplot(z, facet = NULL) + scale_x_yearqtr()` or the same without the `facet` argument will plot it using ggplot2 graphics using 1 or 5 panels.

This does not use any packages that the question is not already using anyways and works directly with the index in the original `"yearqtr"` class without conversion.

```
library(zoo)

z <- read.zoo(dat, index = "qrtr", split = "group")
z <- merge(z, zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), 1/4))
z <- na.locf(z)
fortify.zoo(z, melt = TRUE)
```

This could alternately be expressed as the following pipeline:

```
library(dplyr) # or library(magrittr)
library(zoo)

dta %>%
    read.zoo(index = "qrtr", split = "group") %>%
    merge(zoo(, start(z), end(z), 1/4)) %>%
    na.locf %>%
    fortify.zoo(melt = TRUE)
```

**Updates**  Have added pipeline and made a number of wording improvements and clarifications.